# How to implement Cursor Loader in MVP pattern?

Tags: android, dagger-2, mvp, android-mvp

I'm trying to create Login activity in app based on MVP pattern. User input will be sent to the database using Cursor Loader.

**1#** Is it the correct way to pass user input from view to model, using presenter(and there's validation included) and in model provide it using other db provider class?

```
public class LoginActivityModel extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginActivityMVP.Model, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private ApplicationModule applicationModule;

@Override
public void sendUserToDb(String firstName, String secondName, Uri currentUserUri) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());

    values.put(UserEntry.COLUMN_USERNAME, firstName);
    values.put(UserEntry.COLUMN_PASSWORD, secondName);
    values.put(UserEntry.COLUMN_DATE, date);

    if (currentUserUri != null) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    Uri newUri = applicationModule.provideContext().getContentResolver().insert(UserEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
    if (newUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationModule.provideContext(), "failed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationModule.provideContext(), "succeed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**2a#** If yes, how can I inject context from my view? I tried, as you can see above, to get context injected in root appliaction module but it doesn't work. I've got null context from App. Any other way that I found here, on stackoverflow didn't work.

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

private Application application;

public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Context provideContext() {
    return application;
}
}
```

Also, my App

```
public class App extends Application {

private ApplicationComponent component;
public LoginActivity login;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .loginActivityModule(new LoginActivityModule())
            .build();
}

public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}
}
```

**2b#** If no, how should I implement Cursor Loader into MVP pattern based appliaction? Or maybe is it a bad practice?

Comment: "User input will be sent to the database using Cursor Loader" -- why? Why not just work with the database directly, or by using some object wrapper (e.g., Room)? Why are you using a `ContentProvider` here?

Comment: I thought it's a good practice to use ContentProvider. So, can I just insert data to the database direclty from my sendUserToDb method? 
Something like this: db.insert(UserEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values)

Comment: "I thought it's a good practice to use ContentProvider" -- only if you need to make the database contents available to third-party apps. "can I just insert data to the database direclty from my sendUserToDb method?" -- yes, though you should make sure that all disk and network I/O are done on background threads.